# Error resetting retainedByRelease property of a build in build pipeline through PowerShell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to set the value of retainedByRelease property of a build in one of my build pipelines by calling Azure Rest API through PowerShell. I am getting "page not found" error in the terminal. I suspect I am preparing the URL wrong but not sure where. Please help.

To figure out the URL, I got the area id from the below link for Build (which is 5d6898bb-45ec-463f-95f9-54d49c71752e).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http#resource-area-ids-reference

Got the personalized token from VSO.

Below is what the script looks like (masked the token and the build id):

```
$orgURL = "https://dev.azure.com"

$personalToken = "*******"

$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization="Bearer $token"}

$areaId = "5d6898bb-45ec-463f-95f9-54d49c71752e"

$orgResourceAreasUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/resourceAreas/{1}?api-version=5.0-preview.1",$orgURL,$areaId)

$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgResourceAreasUrl -Headers $header

$basrUrl = $results.locationUrl
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($basrUrl + '_apis/build/builds/<someBuildId>?api-version=3.2') -Method Patch -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{"retainedByRelease"='false'}) -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" | Out-Null
```

I am getting the error on the last line on `Invoke-RestMethod` call.

I am trying this because the build pipeline underneath is throwing some compliance error and I need to remove that pipeline and I am not able to delete it as this build is being retained by the release.

P.S, I have already checked the below links.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/442784/one-or-more-builds-associated-with-the-requested-p.html - looks like the permanent fix is not in place yet
https://almguide.net/2018/12/13/build-blocked-by-release/

Comment: What is the value of `baseUrl`?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk https://tfsprodwus23.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -Uri ($basrUrl + 'https://tfsprodea1.visualstudio.com/')

The error caused by this incorrect url constructed. You can use `Write-Host  $orgResourceAreasUrl` to print out the url you constructed previous, and you will see that the values of `$results.locationUrl` is `https://tfsprodea1.visualstudio.com/` instead of `https://dev.azure.com/{your org name}/`. So, in fact, at the last line of script, the value of url you constructed is `https://tfsprodea1.visualstudio.com/_apis/build/builds/<someBuildId>?api-version=3.2`. This is not a correct url which can be identified by Azure Devops. The correct url should be `https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/build/builds/{build id}?api-version=3.2`

The **root cause** of this error is that the value you specified to **orgURL** is not correct. For correct the error you received, you should change the value of `$orgURL` and specify it as the below shown:

```
$orgURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{your org name}"
```

Only this, you can get the correct value of `locationUrl`.

In addition, at the line of script, the url you constructed is

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/build/builds/{build id}?api-version=3.2
```

This is a definition message which is organization level, you could not **UPDATE** it with token. Or you will receive the message **The project with id 'No project was specified.' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.**.

If you still want to update the value of **retainedByRelease**, please construct the url as

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds/{build id}?api-version=3.2
```

And this is a project level info which can be updated with token.

So, based on your script, I made some change:

```
[String]$project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
$orgURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{your org name}"
$header = @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
$areaId = "5d6898bb-45ec-463f-95f9-54d49c71752e"
$orgResourceAreasUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/resourceAreas/{1}?api-version=5.0-preview.1",$orgURL ,$areaId)

$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgResourceAreasUrl -Headers $header
$basrUrl = $results.locationUrl

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($basrUrl + $project + '/_apis/build/builds/{build id }?api-version=3.2') -Method Patch -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{"retainedByRelease"='false'}) -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" | Out-Null
```

Note: Enable the below checkbox first so that you can use the [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#systemaccesstoken) in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even after replacing the Org Name and build id in your script I am getting the same error. I have replaced the pre-defined variable with the actual name of the project in the first line because "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT" is not returning anything.

Comment: P.S. I have checked the checkbox to allow the OAUTH token in the build pipeline

Comment: @soumyadebghoshal it's wired, these script can replace the value of `RetainedByRelease` successfully.

Comment: @soumyadebghoshal Do you mean for you there’s no value returned in “`env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT”`?

Comment: yes it's an empty string. Let me know if I can give you more details on the script I am running.

Comment: I am getting this error to be precise:
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion the build id I was passing was wrong. I corrected it and now I am seeing the below error.

The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.

Please let me know what level of authorization I need to have to perform this.

Comment: Which token are you trying? PAT? Or enable the the checkbox to allow the OAUTH token? I tried with PAT and has the same error with ` "The user '' is not authorized to access this resource"`  yesterday. But the error disappeared while I try with the OAUTH token checkbox.

Comment: I have tried again on my side, and it's succeed with enabling the OAUTH token checkbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am able to switch the flag now with OAUTH token.

Comment: So, you can replace the value of `retainedByRelease` successfully with this script now?

Comment: Sure, I did that. Thanks again.